# Mysqldb: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

When running following code for importing a csv to a mysql databate I get the error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I know I have 12 columns and 12 values, so where is the error coming from?

```
csv_data = csv.reader('demofile3.csv')
for row in csv_data:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO producten(offerId, ean, conditionName, conditionCategory, conditionComment, bundlePricesPrice, fulfilmentDeliveryCode, stockAmount, onHoldByRetailer, fulfilmentType, mutationDateTime, referenceCode) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11]))
```

contents of CSV file (first 2 lines, 47 in total):

```
offerId,ean,conditionName,conditionCategory,conditionComment,bundlePricesPrice,fulfilmentDeliveryCode,stockAmount,onHoldByRetailer,fulfilmentType,mutationDateTime,referenceCode
02822cf7-d29e-4f94-a3f3-29a22007ab16,0655160828881,NEW,NEW,,11.95,24uurs-12,0,false,FBR,2020-11-10 16:51:43.329 UTC,
```

Comment: So I checked you "first tow lines" and it appears that `referenceCode` doesn't have a value assigned. Last value is `2020-11-10 16:51:43.329 UTC` and seems to be for `mutationDateTime`.

Comment: You're right, referenceCode and conditionComment are always empty

Comment: print each line before the cursor.execute to find the bad row.

Comment: Also when you make sure that you have your lines complete, try `cursor.execute("your query", tuple(rows))` instead of `cursor.execute("your query", (rows[0], ..., rows[10]))`

Comment: All lines print just fine:

for row in csv_data:
    print(row)

Returns:   

['offerId', 'ean', 'conditionName', 'conditionCategory', 'conditionComment', 'bundlePricesPrice', 'fulfilmentDeliveryCode', 'stockAmount', 'onHoldByRetailer', 'fulfilmentType', 'mutationDateTime', 'referenceCode']